# How to export data from user modx database to form?

Tags: php, database, code-snippets, modx

I've table in modx database (orders), and i need to export data from that db to  table at site. 
I pushing into db with following snipept

```
<?php
function agregarCargas( &$fields )
    {
        global $modx;
        // Init our array
        $dbTable = array();
                $dbTable['subject'] = $modx->db->escape($fields['subject']);
        $dbTable['fullname'] = $modx->db->escape($fields['fullname']);
        $dbTable['message']     = $modx->db->escape($fields['message']);
        // Run the db insert query
        $dbQuery = $modx->db->insert($dbTable, 'orders' );
        return true;
    }
?>
```

How can i export from DB? Snippet or? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by exporting?

Comment: pushing values from bd to form

Answer (score 0):

*(Old thread, just for new folks trying to tackle this...)*

Looking at the API you're using I'm guessing you are stuck with an old MODx version. (Evolution)

You should take a look at [the API::DB docs for MODX Evolution](http://rtfm.modx.com/evolution/1.0/developers-guide/api-reference/dbapi)

Something along the lines of the following would fill your HTML table:

```
$res        = $modx->db->select("subject, fullname", 'orders');
$res_rows   = $modx->db->makeArray($res);
$rows       = "";
for($n=0;$n<count($res_rows);$n++){
    $rows  .= "<tr><td>".$res_rows['subject']."</td><td>".$res_rows['fullname']."</td></tr>\n";
}
return $rows;
```

(Of course you should use chunks instead of hardcoded HTML)